# How can you check if a list with string values is similar to another list?

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

**I’m trying to write an algorithm that takes a sample order (string) and extract food name and quantity size from it.**

The issue I’m running into is, if the sample order contains plural version of the food my algorithm does not count it as a match. For example, if it’s searching for banana and it finds bananas doesn’t consider it as banana.

Look how my code can get the correct output for `sample_order1` but not `sample_order2`

```
sample_order1 = 'Can I have a mango and three banana'
sample_order2 = 'Can I have a mango and three bananas'
output for sample_order1 = {'mango': 'one', 'banana': 'three'} <- correct
output for sample_order2 = {'mango': 'one'} <- incorrect (should be the same output as sample_order1 )
```

Here is my code:

```
# List of items served in the restraunt
food_names = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango']

# Sample orders
sample_order1 = 'Can I have a mango and three banana'
sample_order2 = 'Can I have a mango and three bananas'

number = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
final = {}


def order_format(sample_order, num_list, final_output):
    prev_pointer = 0
    current_pointer = 0
    so_fixed = sample_order.split()

    for num in range(0, len(so_fixed)):
        # checks if current word is in list of food names
        if so_fixed[current_pointer] in food_names:
            # if numbers from 0 - current pointer identify food or last identified food to current identified food
            # has a number anywhere in front of food
            for i in range(prev_pointer,current_pointer):
              if so_fixed[i] in num_list:
                new_quantity = so_fixed[i]
                # {found food : quantity of order}
                final_output[so_fixed[current_pointer]] = new_quantity
              else:
                # {found food : default quantity of 1}
                final_output[so_fixed[current_pointer]] = "one"
            prev_pointer = current_pointer
            current_pointer += 1
        else:
            current_pointer += 1
    return final_output


if any(word in sample_order1 for word in food_names):
    order_format(sample_order1, number, final)
    print(final)
# clear final{}
final = {}
if any(word in sample_order2 for word in food_names):
    order_format(sample_order2, number, final)
    print(final)
```

Comment: You might be able to use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric to determine the "distance" between pairs of words (assuming the two aren't too different). Another would be to use the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) phonetic algorithm (there are some third party modules available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=Soundex)). Lastly, you could just see if the two words differ only in that one ends with `s` or `es` but not the other.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up checking if words ended with s/es would be a match if they wornt already one. Going forward I think I might train a ML model for this

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is your program does not detect the pural of the words right?

to slove that problem you can use `for-loop` and `if` statements to and the purals

Heres the code:

```
for i in range(len(food_names)):
    if food_names[i] in sample_order2 or f"{food_names[i]}s" in sample_order2 or f"{food_names[i]}es" in sample_order2 or f"{food_names[i]}'s" in sample_order2 or f"{food_names[i]}'es" in sample_order2:
        # You can place your code here
```